# ¿Comó hacer un ListView Scrollable verticalmente, si se encuentra dentro de un Contraint Layout?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Tengo algunos problemas a la hora de hacer la ListView scrollable quisiera saber como puedo lograr el resultado.

Este es código.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.benchmarkaudio.ResultsTest">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:onClick="eventPlay"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    tools:text="@string/button2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/label1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/grafica"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/grafica2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/milista2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/milista2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/grafica2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/original"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/grafica" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/recording"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/grafica"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285" /> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu declaracion del Constraint agrega `match_parent` en el height

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.benchmarkaudio.ResultsTest">
```

y en la declaracion del ListView agrega el `toTopOf`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/milista2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/grafica2" />
```